# Java - issues comparing Calendar to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, java-8, calendar, localdate, localdatetime

I have the following comparison in my `Java` code:

```
if(appointment.getEndDate().after(LocalDateTime.now()){

//do something
}
```

note that `endDate` field is a `Calendar` type.

Are there any issues with doing a comparison between `Calendar` and `LocalDateTime` this way, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Many things to consider, but the gist of it being that it wouldn't be wise to compare two different sorts of time units. I prefer LocalDateTime to work with. Here's a link to convert, if you can't get rid of the Calendar. https://www.javaprogramto.com/2020/08/how-to-convert-calendar-to-localdatetime-in-java-8.html

Comment: I recommend that you neither use `Calendar` nor `LocalDateTime` for this. For a point in time that you can compare to another point in time use `Instant` or another class that defines a point in time. `LocalDateTime` does not. And the `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any issues with doing a comparison between Calendar and
> LocalDateTime this way, or is there a better way to do it?

Yes, it will give you an incorrect result. Moreover, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

You should convert the `Calendar` object into `Instant` and then you can do the rest of the things using the modern date-time API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // A sample calendar object
        String strDateTime = "10/02/2021 22:25";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse(strDateTime);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);

        Instant instant = calendar.getTime().toInstant();

        // Change the ZoneId as per your requirement e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();

        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(zoneId);

        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);

        System.out.println(zdt.isAfter(now));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

#### Update

Thanks, [Ole V.V. for your valuable feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66492453/java-issues-comparing-calendar-to-localdatetime/66492887#comment117558628_66492887):.

> If the OP cannot afford to upgrade the appointment class to return a
> modern type (like `ZonedDateTime`) for end date-time, this is the way
> to go. `Calendar` too has a [toInstant method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toInstant--), so you can do with
> simply `Instant instant = calendar.toInstant();`. For creating a
> sample old-fashioned `Calendar` I would use like
> `GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 10, 2, 22, 25, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault()))`

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: If the OP cannot afford to upgrade the appointment class to return a modern type (like `ZonedDateTime`)  for end date-time, this is the way to go. `Calendar` too has a [`toInstant` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toInstant()), so you can do with simply `Instant instant = calendar.toInstant();`. For creating a sample old-fashioned `Calendar` I would use like `GregorianCalendar.from(ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 10, 2, 22, 25, 0, 0, ZoneId.systemDefault()))`.

Answer (score 3):

You should not compare a `Calendar` with a `LocalDateTime` object. As per the documentation, this wil **[always](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after(java.lang.Object))** return `false`

> Returns whether this Calendar represents a time after the time
> represented by the specified Object. This method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> compareTo(when) > 0
> ```
>
> if and only if when is a Calendar instance. Otherwise, the method returns false.

You need to convert your Calendar to a `LocalDateTime` before comparing it with another `LocalDateTime`

You can do a conversion with the following code

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(calendar.toInstant(), calendar.getTimeZone().toZoneId());
```

Comment: [The implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/f5b2f089124d3934779a7db1a2874e01afb7ef3e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Calendar.java#L2796) supports that documentation; it checks `instanceof Calendar`.